# Cannot bind to property of object returned by rest service

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, data-binding

This is probably a very basic thing am doing wrong so you will have to forgive my ignorance but I am just learning Angular and I have hit a really annoying roadblock and I can't seem to get find anything relevant with my google searches.

I am following a tutorial that fetches some static JSON data for shipping costs and binds it a shipping component. I have a service that fetches the data, which looks like this but I have removed code unrelated to this question.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CartService {

  constructor(
     private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getShippingPrices() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/shipping.json');
  }

}
```

The shipping component code looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CartService } from '../cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shipping',
  templateUrl: './shipping.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shipping.component.css']
})
export class ShippingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService
  ) { }

  shippingCosts;

  ngOnInit() {
        this.shippingCosts = this.cartService.getShippingPrices();
  }

}
```

And the markup like this:

```
<div class="shipping-item" *ngFor="let shipping of shippingCosts | async">
  <span>{{ shipping.type }}</span>
  <span>{{ shipping.price | currency }}</span>
</div>
```

This all works with the example data from the tutorial which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Overnight",
    "price": 25.99
  },
  {
    "type": "2-Day",
    "price": 9.99
  },
  {
    "type": "Postal",
    "price": 2.99
  }
]
```

However, what I actually want to do is call a web service that returns data that is more like this:

```
{"shipping":[
  {
    "type": "Overnight",
    "price": 25.99
  },
  {
    "type": "2-Day",
    "price": 9.99
  },
  {
    "type": "Postal",
    "price": 2.99
  }
]}
```

When I last used angular back in the days of yore before the schism and angular was what is now called angularjs I think I could just do something like this:

```
<div class="shipping-item" *ngFor="let shipping of shippingCosts.shipping | async">
  <span>{{ shipping.type }}</span>
  <span>{{ shipping.price | currency }}</span>
</div>
```

That doesn't seem to work now, it just fails to do anything, no errors, nothing rendered in the browser, no ajax call to fetch the data, nothing that I can detect.

I also think I that back in those prehistoric days I could do something like this instead:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let temp = this.cartService.getShippingPrices();
    this.shippingCosts = temp.shipping;
  }
```

Which also fails to do anything, in a similar manner to trying to bind to the property, no errors, no rendering of anything, no ajax calls to fetch the data.

So my question is this how do I bind to an array that is one level deep into the data that gets returned.

Comment: I have tried your scenario in stackblitz and my findings are I just did what you were tried, the only thing i changed is that i removed the asyc pipe from *ngFor. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2pxc5l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html     @Ben Robinson

Comment: You’re almost there is seems. Change this: “let shipping of shippingCosts.shipping | async” to “let shipping of (shippingCosts | async)?.shipping” and it should work.

Comment: @MikeOne That seems to work, I am not quite sure I understand the syntax. If you have time to add this as an answer and maybe explain the syntax a little I would be very grateful.

Comment: On mobile, so hard to make a well formatted answer. Basically, the async pipe needs an observable to subscribe to. So shippingCosts is the actual observable you need for the async pipe: (shippingCosts | async). The .shipping part is a property on the emitted value. The question mark is the safe operator, that prevents trying to ‘read’ the property before the actual observable has emitted the object you need.

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks, that's very helpful I think I understand.

Answer (score 1):

the http requests are asynchonous. When you do this

```
this.shippingCosts = this.cartService.getShippingPrices();
```

an Observable is stored in shippingCosts and not the data you spect. You must do the follow

```
this.cartService.getShippingPrices()
   .subscribe(costs => {
      this.shippingCosts = cost;
   });
```

Personally I like to work with promisses in cases like this

```
this.cartService.getShippingPrices().toPromise()
   .then(costs => {
        this.shippingCosts = cost;
   })
   .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
   });
```

Also you can move the request to the service to an async method and invoke it like this

```
async loadShippingCart() {
   this.shippingCosts = await this.cartServices.getShippingPrices().toPromise();
}
```

and then you invoke this from ngOnInit method

Hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful, I had no idea I could use an async/await pattern. I've been out of the programming game for several years and things have obviously moved on quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong in here:

```
<div class="shipping-item" *ngFor="let shipping of shippingCosts.shipping | async">
  <span>{{ shipping.type }}</span>
  <span>{{ shipping.price | currency }}</span>
</div>
```

It should be like this:

```
<div class="shipping-item" *ngFor="let shipping of (shippingCosts | async)?.shipping">
  <span>{{ shipping?.type }}</span>
  <span>{{ shipping?.price | currency }}</span>
</div>
```

So, the thing is that you first need to get observable value async with this: `(shippingCosts | async)` and then get whatever value you need from it, like `?.shipping`.

Bonus tip: Always use elvis operator `?` to escape possible app crash when object property is null, undefined, etc, (e.g.`shipping`)

Comment: Somebody already explained this in the comments but thank you for taking the time to answer anyway it was very helpful.